# How do I link GitLab to Outlook?

Tags: outlook, gitlab

We use  a hosted solution for GitLab and have the issue where people will @ to people but those people are not it.  I would like to link the Outlook OOO message to the GitLab status somehow but this does not seem to be a built in feature and is therefore outside the scope of support.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there isn't any such feature in GitLab today.

However, if the user has notifications on, [automatic OOO email replies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-automatic-out-of-office-replies-from-outlook-9742f476-5348-4f9f-997f-5e208513bd67), and the instance has [reply by email](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email.html) configured, then whenever that person is mentioned while out of office, their OOO email reply to the notification email *should* cause a comment to be made in response indicating they are out of office.

That's probably the closest you'll get without building your own complicated integration.

When I'm OOO, I usually set my status in GitLab accordingly with a palm tree emoji.  `I am OOO until 3/23`. That may also help.

Comment: tbh I am lucky if I can get them to set their Outlook OOO.  Getting them to do it in Gitlab too would be like nailing jelly to the wall!